# How to set the value of Tinymce in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, tinymce

I am using `CakePHP` 2.4.1 and `Tinymce` for `CakePHP2`. I have an Edit page and I want to give some default text (extracted from the database) to one of the `<textarea>'s`. Using plain Cake code I have this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('conditii_plata',array(
    'value'=>$conditii_plata[0]['Setare']['value'], 
    'escape'=>false,
    'type' => 'textarea',
));
```

My question: If I convert it to `Tinymce` I can't give it a default value. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot without setting the text from Javascript upon TinyMCE init.

You could make your textarea hidden and have a second textarea deal with TinyMCE
In your document ready javascript function:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '<id of your second textarea>',
    ....
    setup : function(editor){
        editor.on('init', function(e){
            //copy from hidden textarea
            editor.setContent($('<1st textarea id').val());
        });
    });
});
```

Then your should manually submit your form and before sending copy the tinymce content to your hidden textarea.

Another aproach is to encode your data to json and deal with it from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default value:

```
echo $this->Tinymce->input('model', array('label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'default'=>'Your text'));
```